# Reading(no writing) same file by two process in .net

Tags: c#, .net, xml, console-application

I have a 4GB big XML file and i have a two functionalities need to be done on the same file.I am using two exe's ie two processes to read the big XML file(No write only reading) in order to fasten the process ,when i used `Task` i missed information so i desided to go with process.Does that make any issues by using `xmlreader`?

Comment: What do you mean that 'missed information'?

Comment: Reading the same file by two different Tasks or Process shouldn't make any real difference.  It sounds like your xmlreader is bad.  Try running the two functionalities one at a time and see if you miss the information.